# Remove one column name in Splunk chart

Tags: data-visualization, splunk

I'm receiving data involving the status of various prefixed servers, something like the following:

```
twserv1: UP
twserv2: UP
poserv1: DOWN
poserv2: UNKNOWN
```

I want to display this data in a table separated by the prefix and server name like the following:

```
              TW        PO
serv1         UP        DOWN
serv2         UP        UNKNOWN
```

I've got this mostly working with the following command courtesy of [this Q&A](https://community.splunk.com/t5/Splunk-Search/How-to-place-and-sort-data-in-a-table-for-a-single-event-based/m-p/205757):

```
| inputlookup serverStatus
| table twserv* poserv*
| eval temp=1
| untable temp key value
| rex field=key "(?<x>tw|po)(?<y>\w+\d+)"
| chart values(value) over y by x
| rename tw as TW po as PO
```

This yields something like the following:

```
y             TW        PO
serv1         UP        DOWN
serv2         UP        UNKNOWN
```

Is there any way to remove just that first column title? I've tried setting it to whitespace, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That column "title" is really a field name (in this case, "`y`")

Field names cannot be *just* whitespace ... because then they "don't exist"

Comment: Is there a way to not display that field name in the chart?

Comment: @SeanDuggan - can you chare a screenshot?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Work system. But I provided a text representation of how the chart displays in my question. I'd be happy with a table too. I just haven't figured out how to set it up that way. I'm new to Splunk, trying to retrofit existing code to the new specifications.

Comment: @SeanDuggan - you can do a `| rename y as some_other_name`. Or you can edit the chart's properties in the visualization editor.

Comment: I've renamed two of the columns, but attempting to rename that one column to whitespace raises an error. And I have not found the right property in the visualization editor to turn off one column's title.

Comment: @SeanDuggan - as I said already - you cannot rename a field to whitespace. Not supported. You can only rename to other text (that text may have whitespace if you do something like `| rename field as "Field with white space"`

Comment: Ultimately, UX decided to use a column name, so I'm accepting your answer as at least partially answering my question by indicating that it is impossible.